# Restoring pattern to ArrayList of CheckBox?

Tags: java, arraylist, checkbox

Its a beatBox program with 256 checkBoxes and to make a track and run it . 
With start , stop , loadTrack and saveTrack options.
When we click start button it loops over all checkBoxes and make a track with them. Below is code that restore values of checkBoxes , through JFileChooser and FileInput Stream.

```
void buildAndStartTrack(){

ArrayList checkBoxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
for ( int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox();
        c.setSelected(false);
        checkBoxList.add(c);
        mainPanel.add(c);
    } // end loop
  }
//here some more code to maketracks and start sequencer
}

public class MyObjectLoadListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        JFileChooser fileLoad = new JFileChooser();
        fileLoad.showOpenDialog(theFrame);
        LoadedFile(fileLoad.getSelectedFile());

    }
}

public void LoadedFile(File file)
{
    boolean [] checkBoxState = null;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        checkBoxState = (boolean[]) is.readObject();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Restoring values of checkBoxes and than it will invoke buildAndStartTrack

```
//how i did it myself (It has a bug but its working fine)       
for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();
        if(checkBoxState[i])
        {
            check.setSelected(true);
            checkBoxList.set(i, check);
        }
        else
        {
            check.setSelected(false);
            checkBoxList.set(i, check);
        }
    }

    sequencer.stop();
    buildTrackAndStart();
}
```

Than i looked at the book and found this code .I am not able to get it even after two days searching over checkBoxs, arraylist topics all over internet and forums.

```
for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkBoxList.get(i);
        if(checkBoxState[i])
        {
            check.setSelected(true);  // here doubt
 // check is on left handside  
 // so changing its value shouldn't effect value on right hand side i.e    checkBoxList.get(i)
        }
        else
        {
            check.setSelected(false);
        }
```

But assignment on left hand side is effecting value on right hand side .

Comment: which line you have a problem with? the `setSelected()`? or the `checkBoxList.get(i)`?

Comment: JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkBoxList.get(i);

Comment: Last for loop @XtremeBaumer

Comment: and how does the assignment affect the value in `checkBoxList.get(i)`?

Comment: Yes @XtremeBaumer How does it effect the value

Comment: you said it would affect the value, but it should not affect the value in any way. read your very last sentence

Comment: can i post the full code so that you can run it and check it and where should i post the full code !!

Comment: I know it should not but it is effecting !!

Comment: and how does it affect it? in which way? maybe post it on pastebin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will affect the value because when you do `JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkBoxList.get(i);`, you assign to the `check` reference for the `checkBoxList.get(i)` instance. And then you are performing `check.setSelected(true);` on that instance (remember - it is still the same instance).

Comment: I get it ,check is referring to same checkBox on heap so changing it value will change value of checkBox at index i , in checkBoxList Array. Thankyou @nigol .

Comment: @Gill Just curious - why my answer is not accepted anymore?

Comment: Done @MartinPolak, Sir

Answer (score 1):

`JCheckBox` is a reference type.

When you do an assignment statement:

```
someVariable = someValue;
```

if both sides are of reference types, then something really cool happens.

Reference type variables store a reference to the actual object i.e. the check box itself. The above statement is assigning the reference that `someValue` holds to `someVariable`. In other words, it makes `someVariable` and `someValue` refer to the same object.

Now on to this line

```
JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkBoxList.get(i);
```

As I said, `check` and `checkBoxList.get(i)` will now refer to the same check box, because they are reference type variables. When you say:

```
check.setSelected(true);
```

It is equivalent to:

```
checkBoxList.get(i).setSelected(true);
```

because the two variables refer to the same check box.